# What brand of SSD does apple use for their LATE 2011 MacBook Pros?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

The ones that came out on **October 2011**. Models #:

> MD311*/A,  MD313*/A,  MD314*/A,  MD318*/A  or MD322*/A

The SSD options are listed here with no detailed information:

http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MD322LL/A?select=select&product=MD322LL%2FA

Note that https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9113/what-brand-of-ssd-come-optional-on-macbook-pros is NOT a duplicate question as the answer is not specific to these model #'s

Comment: Some advice - Apple generally has multiple drives sourced and often gets custom firmware loaded on them that is generally unavailable should you be looking to get an "equivalent". Also, often components change over time even when the model does not, so take any answers with this bit of information.

Comment: They use two: Toshiba and Samsung. Both deliver top reliability compared to most of the aftermarket products.

Comment: @cksum thanks, but do you have any reliable source to verify?

Comment: @cksum I would also like to see the source of the statement.

Comment: @AlexCuervo http://www.engadget.com/2011/07/25/psa-apple-using-slower-ssds-in-some-macbook-air-models-video/ As you can see, they explicitly compare two models (and make no mention of any other manufacturers): Samsung and Toshiba. And out of the 12 pages of comments, no one has said, "mine didn't come with either, it came with 'x'". You won't find a definitive answer unless you wrangle the information from an Apple exec in the know. The best we have are user accounts. And to date, ALL Apple devices owners are reporting either Toshiba or Samsung.

Comment: I can confirm cksum is correct.  Apple source Samsung and Toshiba SSDs.  How do I know?  Because I work in the sales and service of Apple products.

Comment: With the comments, this is clear that there isn't a clear answer. Furthermore, this question would be better if it asked why - what is the next step. Rather than asking what (which is Wikipedia,s purpose) perhaps this should ask the general - how do I determine the brand of an SSD in general on X).

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Apple SSD which is OEMed from Toshiba.  The model is TS256C. http://www.tuaw.com/2011/04/17/apple-adds-speedier-ssds-to-latest-batch-of-macbook-airs/

When installing this SSD into my later 2008 MBP, the TRIM is automatically enabled in Lion.  However, other brand SSD, you may need to manually enable the TRIM.

So I guess the later 2011 MBP may using the same OEMed Toshiba SSD.

[image]

Comment: It's a good answer but you didn't actually answer the question. Like the article you linked to discusses, Apple uses Samsung and Toshiba, exclusively. Maybe you want to add that to what you have there?

Comment: Agreed cksum, my SSD from Apple is a APPLE SSD TS512C which is a Toshiba and I'm pretty sure their current preferred SSD is from Samsung. They're using both but the Samsung has better specs. However, Apple and Samsung are suing each other over various UI issues so no doubt there is pressure to use parts from other vendors.

Comment: @kukko: Thanks for your time, but your answer is mostly related to **MacBook Airs**, which use a completely different type of SSD because of their form factor.

Comment: @Ricahrd is your Macbook Pro a **Late 2011** model with a factory installed SSD?

Comment: @kukoo it is not clear if the screen shot provided is of a **Late 2011** model or your **Later 2008** to which you installed an SSD later. Please Clarify

Comment: Sorry guys.  My MPB is a later 2008 15".  When I tried to upgrade to SSD, I searched the web and found some information saying Apple OEM the Toshiba SSD.  So I bought the Toshiba TS256C.  After installed into Lion, the system preference shows it is APPLE SSD TS256C.  As @Richard said, I cannot sure the later 2011 is still using the Toshiba.