# Are there any SSD drives not from Apple for which you can enable TRIM without hacking OS X's kernel?

Tags: ssd, trim

I would like to see if there is a way of getting TRIM support on SSD drives gotten from other manufacturers.

As far as I know, Apple does not produce SSD drives so if I get a similar drive not from them it should work? Or maybe they have custom firmware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Enabling TRIM on third party SSDs

You can enable TRIM on third party SSDs by using a tool called **[Trim Enabler](http://www.groths.org/?page_id=322)**  which "works by patching a kernel extension, and also includes some SMART data to check the health of the SSD drive". [[1](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/03/enable-trim-all-ssd-mac-os-x-lion/)]

I don't know if buying similar drive will get you TRIM to be auto-enabled in Lion. User [@kukoo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9441/kukoo) reports that he has bought an **OEM-SSD** which auto-enabled TRIM in Lion after installation. [[2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32169/13414)]

According to user [@bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike), Apple usually uses **custom firmware** . [[3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32161/what-brand-of-ssd-does-apple-use-for-their-late-2011-macbook-pros#comment36877_32161)]

#### Is enabling TRIM necessary?

User [@cksum](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/10355/cksum) has covered this as a part of his [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25237/13414) to a post "Optimize MacBook Pro for internal SSD+HDD drives".

Comment: I replaced the optical disk in my macbook pro with a Sandisk ssd, and built a hackintosh with a Crucial ssd -- both are trim enabled with this method.

Comment: @gentmatt Unfortunately as of Yosemite third-party SSDs do not have TRIM support, and using TRIM Enabler requires disabling kext signing.

Answer (score 0):

OWC's SSDs work great http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/ and have Mac TRIM support.

Comment: @thepen why do you say that? Their site says "OWC SSDs don't require software "hacks" for optimal operation on a Mac. OWC SSDs start fast and stay fast, and are compatible with all versions of OS X, including Yosemite."

Comment: Sorry, that comment was meant for an above post, now relocated. Garbage collection and TRIM work differently, and AFAIK Apple has disabled TRIM on 3rd party drives as of Yosemite. Absence of TRIM support is less of an issue with active GC. Glad to hear if lack of TRIM isn't affecting you! –  Cheers