# SSD OEM Exact Model, Part Number and Manufacturer in MacBook Pro (Mid 2012)

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, ssd, repair, system-information

Does anyone know the exact manufacturer, Apple part number or model number of a 512GB SSD drive in a BTO MacBook Pro (Mid 2012)?

I cannot find any teardown photos or System Information screenshots online. This would really help inform my decision on what SSD to purchase.

Note: I am asking for information about specific hardware specs that I can not find anywhere online and are not publicly available from Apple. I am not asking how to use System Information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Samsung 830 (SM512E) for both the Retina and non-Retina Mid-2012 Macbook Pro.

Ref:

- [Apple Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4114259?start=0&tstart=0)
- [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6005/apples-new-ssd-its-fast)
- [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1394062)

Edit: Apple has [also begun to use the Sandisk X100](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6727/apple-is-using-sandisk-ssds-in-retina-macbook-pro-as-well) in Retina Macbook Pros.

Comment: Also, the Anandtech link is a teardown of the Retina model. It is answered at Apple Forums link in the (as of today) last response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Apple menu
2. About this Mac
3. More Info...
4. System Report
5. Serial ATA

I don't know how many vendors produce this size SSD for Apple but I have a 15" early 2011 MacBook Pro with a 512GB SSD in it from Apple and the model is APPLE SSD TS512C.

A search online for "APPLE SSD TS512C" gives me a discussion on this very site:

[What brand of SSD does apple use for their LATE 2011 MacBook Pros?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32161/what-brand-of-ssd-does-apple-use-for-their-late-2011-macbook-pros)

Looks like they were using Toshiba and Samsung back then. That may have changed in a year but I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks. I do not own one of these machines, so I have no access to the System Report. I am looking for the information on the mid-2012 model newer SSD drives.